# F# - The type int is not compatible with type unit

Tags: .net, f#, unit-type

Quite new to functional languages, but I'm maintaining someone else's code with a lot of F#. Can anyone offer some insight into this?

```
        let mtvCap = Rendering.MTViewerCapture(mtViewer)
        mtvCap.GetCapture()
        mtvCap.ToWpfImage()
        grid.Children.Add(mtvCap.ImageElement)
```

MTViewer.ImageViewer is of type System.Windows.Controls.Image, and grid is System.Windows.Controls.Grid.

Again, error is: The type int is not compatible with type unit

Comment: Bravo! Most developers would've wasted time re-writing. I'm glad to see you're doing the right thing: learning the technology.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F# does not allow for you to silently ignore return values.  The type `unit` is F#'s version of `void`.  So the error is saying essentially

> I expected the statement to have no return but instead it returns an int value

Or the opposite.  I tend to incorrectly read this error message.

What's likely happening is one of the following

1. The method in question is expecting an `int` return value but the method `Add` returns void hence F# is just asking for a return value
2. The method in question is typed as `unit` but `Add` is returning an `int` and F# needs you to ignore the value.
3. The `GetCapture` or `ToWpfImage` return values that need to be explicitly handled.

For the last 2 cases you can fix this by passing the value to the `ignore` function

```
mtvCap.GetCapture() |> ignore
mtvCap.ToWpfImage() |> ignore
grid.Children.Add(mtvCap.ImageElement) |> ignore
```

After digging around a bit I believe #2 is the issue because `UIElementCollection.Add` returns an `int` value.  Try modifying the final line to look like this

```
grid.Children.Add(mtvCap.ImageElement) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

I know remarkably little about F#, but as I recall, "unit" is their way of saying "void", so I'm gonna guess that you are trying to assign the "return value" of a function that doesn't have one, to a varaible.  That would make the most likely candidate, this line:

`let mtvCap = Rendering.MTViewerCapture(mtViewer)`

Comment: Answer is technically correct, but you probably want to go with JaredPar's solution if your not interested in the return result (as seems the case here).