# Why is return type of this expression calculated to return type unit-> int instead of int

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and am writing a function to convert a dateTime value to unix timestamp in seconds.
Below is my implementation of such a function (just using builtin function and wrapping it for learning).

```
let DateTimeToUnix x =
        let result = DateTimeOffset(x).ToUnixTimeSeconds
        result
```

Expected return type is: DateTime -> int64
Actual return type is: DateTime-> (unit->int64)

I tried to find similar questions and the closest i found was something like this ([F# - The type int is not compatible with type unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504856/f-the-type-int-is-not-compatible-with-type-unit))
but unfortunately i don't understand how it is applicable in this case since the return type of the function (ToUnixTimeSeconds) used is int64 and not (unit->int64).

It would be great if someone can point to where to learn about this or can explain the behavior. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToUnixTimeSeconds` is a *method*, not a property. In F# methods are modeled as functions. Parameterless methods are modeled as functions with a single `unit`-typed parameter. So the type of `foo.ToUnixTimeSeconds` would be `unit -> int64`, just like the compiler is telling you.

To actually call that function and obtain a result from it, give it a parameter of the type that it expects - i.e. `unit`:

```
let DateTimeToUnix x =
    let result = DateTimeOffset(x).ToUnixTimeSeconds ()
    result
```

---

As a side note, you don't really have to name the intermediate value `result`:

```
let DateTimeToUnix x =
    DateTimeOffset(x).ToUnixTimeSeconds ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke ToUnixTimeSeconds before returning it in order to get the desired return type:

```
let DateTimeToUnix x =
    let result = DateTimeOffset(x).ToUnixTimeSeconds() // invoke method: ()
    result
```